# SharedPreferences could not save key-value as intended

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences

I could not toggle a key-value of onoff. Why the key-value not changed in every button (sound) click?
The default onoff value is 0, on button click the onoff value should change to 1. But it can't. Why?

```
private var mp: MediaPlayer? =null
    var sound_onoff:Int=0

onCreat{...

mp= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.key_tone)


val pref = applicationContext.getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0)
        val editor = pref.edit()

sound_onoff = pref.getInt("onoff", 0)

sound.setOnClickListener{
            when(sound_onoff){
                1->{sound.setText("SOUND ON")
                    mp?.setVolume(1F,1F)
                    mp!!.start()
                    editor.putInt("onoff", 0)
                    editor.apply()}
                0->{sound.setText("SOUND OFF")
                    mp?.setVolume(0F,0F)
                    mp!!.start()
                    editor.putInt("onoff", 1)
                    editor.apply()}
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why don't you use boolean (`getBoolean` / `putBoolean`) for onoff?

Comment: I will try. but can you tell is there any mistakes in my code. thank you

Comment: Maybe, `when(sound_onoff)` is false? Use Log.d to check your variables wherever you want to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use Boolean instead of Int.

And Why your code is not work. Because you put `sound_onoff = pref.getInt("onoff", 0)` just in onCreate so it only call one time when class created.

You need call `sound_onoff = pref.getInt("onoff", 0)` it when you need check it.

Try this:

```
sound.setOnClickListener{
sound_onoff = pref.getInt("onoff", 0)
            when(sound_onoff){
                1->{sound.setText("SOUND ON")
                    mp?.setVolume(1F,1F)
                    mp!!.start()
                    editor.putInt("onoff", 0)
                    editor.apply()}
                0->{sound.setText("SOUND OFF")
                    mp?.setVolume(0F,0F)
                    mp!!.start()
                    editor.putInt("onoff", 1)
                    editor.apply()}
            }
        }
```

Hope this help!